# PhpStorm and xdebug profiler setup on Windows localhost

Tags: php, phpstorm, xdebug, xdebug-profiler

I'm having a hard time getting xdebug profiling to work and to integrate into PhpStorm 2017.  I tried to follow [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_ua_O01IICg) without success.

I know that xdebug is properly installed on the web server (a local Apache on Windows installation) and properly integrated into PhpStorm because when I click *"Start Listening to PHP Debug connections"* in the IDE, my breakpoints stop code execution and I can debug just fine.  I just can't get the profiler to generate its files and I don't even know if it's running.

**php.ini**

```
<!-- language: lang-none -->
[xdebug]
zend_extension="php_xdebug-2.5.5-5.6-vc11.dll"
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
; xdebug.profiler_enable=1          ; I've tried uncommenting. Made no difference
; xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger=1  ; I've tried uncommenting. Made no difference
xdebug.profiler_output_dir="C:\websites\tmp"
xdebug.profiler_output_name="cachegrind.out.%p"
xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM
```

At the start of my PHP execution I've tried to turn on profiling like this:

```
ini_set('xdebug.profiler_enable','1');
```

I've also tried running a script from the command line with the following:

```
php script.php -d xdebug.profiler_enable=1
```

No error is raised. There is no file created in `C:\websites\tmp` either.

I've come across the [easiest Xdebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/the-easiest-xdebug/) extension but I'd rather not rely on another piece of software if it can be avoided (and I haven't even tried it to see whether it would work).

- PHP 5.6
- Apache 2.4
- xdebug 2.5.5
- PhpStorm 2017
- Windows 7 64bit

### Update

I learned about the `xdebug.remote_log` ini directive and set it to a file, then restarted Apache.  Here is what I see in the log when I run a normal debugging session (meaning I clicked *"Start Listening to PHP Debug connections"* in PhpStorm):

```
<!-- language: lang-none -->
Log opened at 2017-07-22 20:33:03
I: Connecting to configured address/port: localhost:9000.
I: Connected to client. :-)
-> <init xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" 
         xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" 
         fileuri="file:///C:/path/to/script.php"...>
   </init>
```

As I said, debugging works alright. Now if don't listen for debugging but try to enable profiler with either a command line parameter `php script.php -d xdebug.profiler_enable=1` or within the script with `ini_set('xdebug.profiler_enable','1')`, this is what the xdebug log shows

```
<!-- language: lang-none -->
Log opened at 2017-07-22 20:38:10
I: Connecting to configured address/port: localhost:9000.
E: Time-out connecting to client. :-(
Log closed at 2017-07-22 20:38:11
```

### Update 2

I was just able to generate the profiler's *cachegrind.out* file! I don't know the exact constraints to make this work yet, but what I did is uncomment the `xdebug.profiler_enable` line my *php.ini* above and restarted Apache.  I still need a way to only enable the profiler on demand as in the video I linked to at the top.  Having it always on in *php.ini* adds too much overhead because most of the time I don't need profiler data

Comment: *"I still need a way to only enable the profiler on demand"* `xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger=1` + browser extension (or manual adding parameter to the URL) does it just fine. So far this is about xdebug config only and nothing to do with PhpStorm.

Comment: @LazyOne Ok so I enable trigger with `xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger=1`, then I remove `xdebug.profiler_enable` right? As for the URL param, do you know what it would be to trigger profiling? Thanks for the info.

Comment: https://xdebug.org/docs/profiler -- all info is there -- `XDEBUG_PROFILE`

Answer (score 0):

This is my working solution:

**php.ini**

```
[Xdebug]
zend_extension=php_xdebug-2.6.0-7.2-vc15.dll
xdebug.default_enable=1
xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
```

**httpd.conf:**

```
Listen 127.0.0.1:80
```

[image]

[image]

[image]